# Using a container as a button to run jquery coin toss game

Tags: jquery, html, css

First question, please forgive me if I am not putting enough in here. I searched high and low and could find answers for JavaScript and other languages but not jQuery. I was working on codecademy and then moved past it with other resources and was trying to work on creating a coin toss website with a CSS made coin that would animate and flip. However, I am stuck at getting my code to run for just the actual result. I was able to get it to work with JavaScript and a button using this code:

```
var x= "heads";
var y= "tails";
function coin(){
return Math.random();
};

function myButton(){
if (coin() > .5){
document.getElementById("myP").innerHTML= x;
} else {
document.getElementById("myP").innerHTML= y;
}
}
```

That worked for a button, but after studying jQuery I found I could make a function run off of an element instead. So I created

```
<input type='image' src='heads.png' class='heads'></input>
```

And then used this script to run if off of my linked .js file.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
function coin(){
  return Math.random();
 }
function toss(){
 if (coin > .5 ){
  $('#myP').append('heads!');
} else {
$('#myP').append('tails!');
 }
}
$('.heads').on('click', function() {
coin();
toss();
});
});
```

Now when I load the page I get a console error that "$" is not defined. It will change the text but only one time. So how do I make it run a new "Math.random()" every time the button is clicked? I thought that including its function first on the click would solve this but no luck. Thanks in advance for the help and sorry if this was too much or not enough info.

Edit: To clarify, the jQuery file and my .js file are linked within script tags in the html(should have included this first)

Comment: Did you add the `<script>` link for jQuery? You need to add this: `<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>` or download the jQuery file and add the correct `<script>` tag.

Comment: I should have included that, but yes I have the file linked within the html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you were comparing a variable that had no value. It also sounds like you may have an issue linking jQuery. This should do what you want.

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function coin(){
         return Math.random();
    }
    function toss(coin){
        if (coin > .5 ){
            $('#myP').text('heads!');
        } else if (coin <= .5) {
            $('#myP').text('tails!');
        } else{
            console.log('error');    
        }
    }
    $('.heads').on('click', function() {
        toss(coin());
    });
});
```

**Demo:** [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hopkins_matt/9u4sk4b5/)

Comment: Boom! Works great now, thanks! Like I said, still new to the website. Is there a way to PM for a few clarifications on the code or do I just have to ask with comments?

Comment: No way to PM. You can ask here, or check the contact info on my profile.